# How can I color specific words on content editable element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I am trying to make a coding editor, my problem is I want to color specific words on a content editable div for example if the user wrote this code: 
`function print(){}; function load(){};` the word "function" should be colored red.

Here's what I have tried, unfortunately it does not work but I wanted to show effort and the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

editor.oninput = () => {
    editor.innerHTML = colorWord(editor.innerHTML, "function");
    caretAtEnd(editor);
}

function colorWord(text, word) {
    while (text.includes(word)) {
        text = text.replace(word, "<span style='color:blue;'>" + word + "</span>");
    }
    return text;
}

function caretAtEnd(element) {
    element.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
        typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(element);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a syntax highlighting plugin, and rather than creating your own, you could use [one that already exists](https://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: wont `text` always include `word` since you are returning a string that still contains `word`, but with a `span` wrapped around it? - try using an `if` instead

Comment: @Nicolas, thanks man  i am going to use syntax highlighting plugin

Comment: i dont want to spend lot of time making my own thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your `while` loop.  If word is in the text, text will always include `word` (since you are just adding to the string) and your `while` loop will never end. Simply change it to an `if`

```js
function colorWord(text, word) {
    if (text.includes(word)) {
        text = text.replace(word, "<span style='color:blue;'>" + word + "</span>");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: but it going to change only first "function" that exist on text

Comment: this shouldn't be the accepted answer by any case

Answer (score 0):

Your function `colorWord(text, word)` will never advance to the next word, in fact, it's an infinite while loop as has already been mentioned.  `.includes` will always find the first instance, and since your code still includes the word when it replaces, it won't ever advance.

Replace however can be global if you're using regex.  Regex and string.replace are what you're looking for:

```
function colorWord(text, word) {
  const re = new RegExp(word, 'gi'); // this will output /word/gi, with 'word' being whatever value the parameter is
  return text.replace(re, `<span style='color:blue;'>${word}</span>`);
}

console.log(
  colorWord('apples are round, and apples are juicy.', 'apples')
)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp