# How to highlight specific words in contenteditable div in html

Tags: javascript, html

Actually I am making a online code editor.
I need to change color of words like "void" , "digitalWrite" etc when user types in my contenteditable div.
For example if anyone types void then color of only void should become red
How can I do these. Here is html

```
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: You could read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Comment: You can add onChange to your div and call the function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59362131/12831292)

Answer (score 0):

try it by adding an input event listener to the div and if there is a keyword like void, then you could surround it with a span with a specific color.
Pls don't do this!!! This is a very big vulnerability because anyone can code for you.
But if you really need this, you can use this code:

```
 document.querySelector(“.editor”).addEventListener(“input”, () => {
   var content = document.querySelector(“.editor”).innerHTML;
   var newContent = content.substr(0, content.search("void")) + "<span>void" + "</span>" + content.substr(content.search("void") + "void".length, content.length);
 }, false);
```

Sry if its not working, I hate coding on phone...